# iPhone memory management (with specific examples/questions)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

Hey all. I know this question's been asked but I still don't have a clear picture of memory management in Objective-C. I feel like I have a pretty good grasp of it, but I'd still like some correct answers for the following code. I have a series of examples that I'd love for someone(s) to clarify.

**Setting a value for an instance variable**:

Say I have an `NSMutableArray` variable. In my class, when I initialize it, do I need to call a `retain` on it?

Do I do

```
fooArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
```

or

```
fooArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Does doing `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` already set the `retain` count to 1, so I wouldn't need to call `retain` on it? On the other hand, if I called a method that I know returns an `autorelease`d object, I would for sure have to call `retain` on it, right? Like so:

```
fooString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d items", someInt] retain];
```

**Properties**:

I ask about the `retain` because I'm a bit confused about how `@property`'s automatic setter works.

If I had set `fooArray` to be a `@property` with `retain` set, Objective-C will automatically create the following setter, right?

```
- (void)setFooArray:(NSMutableArray *)anArray {
    [fooArray release];
    fooArray = [anArray retain];
}
```

So, if I had code like this: `self.fooArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` (which I believe is valid code), Objective-C creates a setter method that calls `retain` on the value assigned to `fooArray`. In this case, will the `retain` count actually be 2?

**Correct way of setting a value of a property**:

I know there are questions on this and (possibly) debates, but which is the right way to set a `@property`?

This?

```
self.fooArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Or this?

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.fooArray = anArray;
[anArray release];
```

I'd love to get some clarification on these examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would want to use the accessors whenever possible, especially when dealing with objects as they help avoid many memory issues. So even for instance variables, you should do:

```
self.fooArray = ...;
```

instead of

```
fooArray = ...;
```

The reason why you should declare properties for object instance variables is because the memory management is slightly more complicated, and recreating it by hand each time is tricky. The correct setter for a nonatomic, retained property would look like:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSArray *)aFoo {
    if (foo == aFoo) {
        return;
    }
    NSArray *oldFoo = foo;
    foo = [aFoo retain];
    [oldFoo release];
}
```

You are right about the instance variable having a retain count of 2 when you do something like this (assuming foo is retained):

```
self.foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

The first retain count is coming from `alloc`, and the second one from your synthesized setter. Any of these should work:

```
// longer, explicit version, releases immediately (more efficient)
NSMutableArray *aFoo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.foo = aFoo;
[aFoo release];

// autoreleased, not so bad unless you're a memory management freak
self.foo = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

// an even shorter version of the above
self.foo = [NSMutableArray array];
```

To create private properties, you can declare them as a class extension in the .m implementation file. To give an example, consider a simple Person object, which has a name, and a boolean property `didSave` which simply indicates whether the object has been saved to some database or not. Since we don't want to expose this to the outside world, but still keep the benefits of properties inside the implementation file, we can create the header file will all instance variables (public, private, protected) and only public properties:

```
// Person.h

@interface Person {
    NSString *name;

    @private
    BOOL didSave;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

@end
```

But declare private properties inside the implementation:

```
// Person.m

// property is declared as a class extension, making it 
// invisible to the outside world.
@interface Person ()
    @property BOOL didSave;
@end

@implementation

// synthesize as normal
@synthesize name, didSave;

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Anurag. I've been trying to avoid properties when I don't need the variables to be accessible by other classes. Kind of a n00b question but... can I have a property not accessible by other classes?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Anurag. If you don't mind, I'd like to ask for a couple of clarification points.. Could you declare the canSave variable in the .m's @interface? It seems to me that variables that aren't exposed are implicitly private already and seems a bit redundant to have to mark it as such.

Comment: I hear you on the private instance variable part, but unfortunately this is the closest we can get to keep implementation details private with Objective-C. IF we don't mark the variables as private, then by default they have protected access, which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 4):

According to Apple's [Object Ownership Policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html), any method that begins with the words `alloc` or `new`, or contains `copy` is owned by the caller.

To obtain ownership of an object, you must `retain` it.

So, in your first example, the `retain` is unnecessary because you already own the object.

The correct way to do this:

```
fooArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Since `autoreleased` objects are owned by the current autorelease pool, you must call `retain` on them to gain ownership of them, so this example is correct:

```
fooString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d items", someInt] retain];
```

This would work fine as well:

```
self.fooString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d items", someInt]; //retained by property setter
```

And for your last example using the property setter, this would be the correct way to do it:

```
NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.fooArray = anArray;
[anArray release];
```

Instead of having to do the above, I'd suggest the following solution:

```
self.fooArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
```

`arrayWithCapacity:` will return an autoreleased `NSMutableArray`, which is the `retain`-ed by the property setter method. :)

Comment: I know creating temp array's objects for assigning property array is good but what is problem associated with self.fooArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];why it gives memory leak.

Comment: @Ishu Gupta, There is a memory leak there since you already own the object because you called `alloc` on that line, and your `@property` setter has the `retain` modifier presumably, so the end result of that assignment becomes `self.fooArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain]`, hence the leak.

Comment: @Ishu Gupta I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: This is really good explanation. Thanks Jacob. Some of my doubt are clear now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with this line:

```
fooArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

fooArray will automatically have a retain count of 1.

Second, yes, it's 2. And your guess on the setter implementation is correct.

Third, the latter one is right