# ViewController doesn't get released

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

Every time I turn the page in my app, I am removing and releasing the previous viewController - but for some reason it is still in memory. I know this, because after using the app for a while, I get 47 memory warnings - one from each view controller - if I had opened 47 pages before the memory warning occurred.  I get 60 memory warnings if I had opened 60 pages before the memory warning occurred.  And so on...

This is the code that runs from page to page:

```
UIViewController *nextController;
Class nextClass = [pageClasses objectAtIndex:(currentPageIndex - 1)];
nextController = [[nextClass alloc] initWithNibName:[pageNibs objectAtIndex:(currentPageIndex - 1)] bundle:nil];
[nextController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];

[currentPageController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:nextController.view];

[currentPageController release];
currentPageController = nextController;
[currentPageController retain];
[nextController release];
```

Can anybody point to any issues they see?

Thanks so much!

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but if I understand your app correctly, you really don't need all of these new view controllers anyway. If you're paging through something and only 2 pages are actually visible at once (the current and part of the next or previous until the current one goes out of view), you can simply re-use two controllers, dynamically updating the content of the off-screen one right before it appears. Recycle the same two over and over. You don't even need to mess around with releasing them until the activity or app is complete.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Each page has a button in a different spot that takes you to the next page. It would get complicated to place more than 50 buttons in Interface Builder and either enabling or disabling them depending on which page the user was on. I suppose i could place the buttons in IB, jot down the x/y and width/heighth of the buttons, delete them - and then programmatically add and remove the appropriate buttons based on the page the user is on. I may end up rewriting the code this way if all else fails...

Comment: If you can simply change the position (and appearance, if necessary) of the buttons then you would again be able to eliminiate the creation and release of button after button.

Answer (score 1):

As as aside, make sure you also `nil` any outlets your viewController has in `viewDidUnload` and generally do the opposite of any corresponding code in `viewDidLoad`.  I see a lot of iOS code which doesn't do this and it stops the runtime properly unloading view controllers and associated views.

Answer (score 0):

Have you played with the Behavior and Memory sections of the Window Attributes panel in IB's Inspector? This is where you usually control memory use and release stuff (outside of the code itself).
Try changing values for the view object in question, as well as on the window (or whatever it is for iPhone).

Comment: I haven't come across any mention of Interface Builder being involved with memory prior to your comment.  If you can provide any additional information about where this "Behavior and Memory section" is in IB, I will look into it...  but I am not sure that this applies to iPhone/iPad development?

Comment: Link to screen cap here: http://s3.amazonaws.com/twitpic/photos/full/217343150.png?AWSAccessKeyId=0ZRYP5X5F6FSMBCCSE82&Expires=1293765636&Signature=VS9wBAHy3rDEX1E%2Fjq56bR6we90%3D I just do Cocoa dev for X, so it may not apply to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're calling `retain` on `currentPageController`. I just recently asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543895/iphone-memory-management-with-specific-examples-questions) and got a ton of clarification on memory management.

EDIT: What if you did something like:

```
[currentPageController.view removeFromSuperview];
[currentPageController release];

Class nextClass = [pageClasses objectAtIndex:(currentPageIndex - 1)];
currentPageController = [[nextClass alloc] initWithNibName:[pageNibs objectAtIndex:(currentPageIndex - 1)] bundle:nil];
[currentPageController performSelector:@selector(setDelegate:) withObject:self];

[self.view addSubview:currentPageController.view];
```

It cleans up the code a bit and won't leak memory.

Comment: If I comment out the retain, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACESS. I definitely need to call retain on this, so this is not the correct solution for me. However, I will read the answers to your similar question and I thank you for answering and trying to help!  =)

Comment: Oops, didn't see the `release` on the `nextController`. I've edited my answer, hopefully that'll help? :)