# Can someone please explain this one line of code on Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

```
eventPoints = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];
```

What does the "retain" keyword do along with the "array"?. "array" is not defined anywhere.

Also eventPoints was declared as a NSMutableArray.

I am just trying to learn. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this question I asked: [iPhone memory management (with specific examples/questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543895/iphone-memory-management-with-specific-examples-questions)

It took me a while to get a hang of this too. Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: As for what `[NSMutableArray array]` does, according to the docs on `NSArray`, it does this: "Creates and returns an empty array." and is used by mutable subclasses of `NSArray`, such as `NSMutableArray`. Basically, it's the same as doing: `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease]` (or something really similar). Because it's `autorelease`d, you need to call `retain` on it to keep the variable.

Answer (score 2):

1) What does the "retain" keyword do along with the "array"?

As you know, objective-C uses referencing counting for memory management. "retain" increments 1 by everyPoints.

2) "array" is not defined anywhere.

"array" is defined in NSArray. NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray, so NSMutableArray can use functions defined in NSArray. "array" is a class method that creates and returns an empty array.

There are four ways to explicitly increment 1 in objective-c: alloc, copy, retain, attain
Because you create an empty array without using any of these, you manually increment 1 by "retain". So in the future, you might need to [everyPoints release] to decrement 1 to deallocate it.