# How does the (retain) accessor work?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, accessor

This question may be answered elsewhere but I haven't seen it.
I've read the Memory Management Guide twice now and still wonder about this.

Imagine I create an instance variable like this...

```
@interface

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSArray *myArray;

@end
```

Now also imagine I get or set myArray using the accessor somewhere in my class.

for example

```
NSArray* arrayInit = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",nil];
self.myArray = arrayInit;
[arrayInit release];
```

By using the accessor method have I increased the retain count of myArray by 1?

My typical dealloc method would look like this:

```
-(void)dealloc{
[myArray release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

A related question is should I always use the accessors when I'm interacting with "myArray".
Is it wise to always to write self.myArray.count for example?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is YES.

It's generally better to use accessors when they exist, so YES again. Note that invoking the accessor can have side effects, depending if it's a custom one, or if KVO is set up for that member. So invoking release directly on the member or setting it to nil through the accessor can lead to different results that you should be aware of.

Comment: So everytime you use a retain accessor you have to release it when your done using it?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a question regarding a lot of this and got some **great** answers here: [iPhone memory management (with specific examples/questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543895/iphone-memory-management-with-specific-examples-questions)

Hope this helps!